# Custom JsonMappingException Mapper not being invoked

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs, jsonexception

I've created a class to override JsonMappingException. Here is my custom exception handler.

```
@Provider
public class JsonMappingExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> {

public JsonMappingExceptionMapper(){
    System.out.println("I am called");
} 

@Override
public Response toResponse( JsonMappingException e ) {

System.out.println("Should be called");
return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .entity("The supplied JSON contained an invalid property: " + "").build();
}
}
```

But this is not being invoked and instead I am getting HTTP 500 error.

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of boolean from String value '': only "true" or "false" recognized
at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@463a4396; line: 5, column: 20]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:160)
```

I have also packaged the compiled custom ExceptionMapper class with my web application project.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons()
{
    Set<Object> singleton = new HashSet<Object>();
    singleton.add(new JsonMappingExceptionMapper());
    return singleton;
}
```

Comment: What's the package of `JsonMappingException` you are importing in your ExceptionMapper?

Comment: import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;

Comment: Is the constructor of the mapper called?

Comment: yes. But the toResponse method is not being invoked.

Comment: I am wondering if there is something that I need to add to web.xml?

Comment: I wouldn't know. I don't use CXF

Comment: Maybe useful .. Take a look ...https://blog.dejavu.sk/2015/03/24/what-to-do-when-jax-rs-cannot-find-its-providers-aka-my-message-body-writer-is-not-used/ .. otherwise share the sample project on github .. will look at it ..